# Classification of the same image gives different result

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to classify 3D images using CNN with Tensorflow and I think something is wrong. After training and validation, I'm using a saved model to classify a single image. When I classify this image, it gives me different results each time I try.

Example:

```
1st try:
   input: Picture of a 3D brain
   result of the classification: 1

2nd try:
   input: Same picture of 3D brain
   result of the classification: 2
```

I wanted to know if that's normal or if I'm doing something wrong. The model I'm using has an accuracy of 67%.

Here's the code:

```
def conv3d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv3d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def maxpool3d(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool3d(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    number = calc()

    weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 3, 1, 32])),
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 3, 32, 64])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number, 1024])),
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, 3]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 50, 50, 30, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool3d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool3d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, number])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, 0.8)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output
```

That's the main function:

```
def classification(path):
    x = tf.placeholder('float')

    new_path = extract(path + '.gz')
    X_new = process_data(path=new_path, apply_hist=True)

    pred = convolutional_neural_network(x)

    res = 0

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('modelo.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, 'modelo')

        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(pred)

        c = sess.run(probabilities, feed_dict={x: X_new})

        res = np.argmax(c)

    return res
```

I'm doing the same processing on the input images.

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

I tried swapping those lines but the results are still different.

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('modelo.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, 'modelo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You first restore your variables, and then after you initialize your variables to random values:

```
saver.restore(sess, 'modelo')
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

So you have two different predictions because you initiliaze your model with random variables twice. You need to swap these lines, or leave out the initialize_all_vars altogehter. To be honest I don't know exactly how to fix it, but at least this sets you on the right path. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help! I tried swapping those lines and it's still giving me different results, but your answer really makes sense, I'll try changing some things in the code to see if it works. Thanks again!